# Method does not exist or incorrect signature- Save Process

Tags: unit-test

I am getting an error in my test class stating "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" in the Save Process().

**Main Class :-**

```
public class AttachmentStatusUsingJSRemotingCtrl {

    public Attachment att {get;set;}
    public Document__c doc {get;set;}
    public Transient Blob resume {get; set;}
    public Boolean isErr {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> contentTypeList {get;set;}
    public String attContentType {get;set;}
    String techViewId;
    public boolean loaderFlag{get;set;}

    public AttachmentStatusUsingJSRemotingCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        loaderFlag = false;
        init();
    }

       private void init(){

        att        = new Attachment();
        doc        = new Document__c();
        techViewId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        doc.Technical_Verification__c = techViewId;
        String flag = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('flg');
        fillUpContents();
        if(flag == 'true'){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.info,'Uploaded successfully...'));
        }
    }

    // fillup to contentTypeList records
    private void fillUpContents(){
        contentTypeList  = new List<SelectOption>();
        contentTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Road with property Visible','Road with property Visible'));
        contentTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Property Front','Property Front'));
        contentTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Material on site','Material on site'));  
        contentTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Interior 1','Interior 1'));
        contentTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Interior 2','Interior 2'));
        contentTypeList.sort();
        attContentType = contentTypeList[0].getValue();
    }

    public  pageReference saveDocument(){
        loaderFlag = true;
         pageReference pg = saveProcess(false);
         return pg;
    }

    public pageReference saveDocumentSF1(){

         pageReference pg = saveProcess(true);
         return pg;
    }

    @testvisible private  pageReference saveProcess(Boolean isSF1){
        isErr = false;


            String code = '';
            String oppName = '';
            String oppLoanNumber = '';
            List<Technical_Verification__c> techObjList = new List<Technical_Verification__c>();
            if(string.isNotBlank(techViewId))
              techObjList  = [select id,Application__c,Application__r.Name, Application__r.Loan_Number__c from Technical_Verification__c where id =: techViewId];

            if(techObjList.size()>0){
                oppName = techObjList[0].Application__r.Name;
                oppLoanNumber = techObjList[0].Application__r.Loan_Number__c;
            }
            oppName = string.isNotBlank(oppName) ? oppName  : '';   
            oppLoanNumber = string.isNotBlank(oppLoanNumber ) ? oppLoanNumber : '';
            System.debug('att--> '+att);
            System.debug('att.Name--> '+att.Name);
            System.debug('att.Body--> '+att.Body);
            code = oppLoanNumber +' = '+oppName;    
            if(String.isNotBlank(attContentType)){
                code = code.trim().startsWith('=') ? code.trim().remove('=') : code;
                string fileName = att.Name;
                string ext = '';
                if(att.Name.contains('.'))
                    ext = att.Name.substring(att.Name.lastIndexOf('.')) ;
                att.Name = code+' = '+attContentType+ext;

                att.Name = att.Name.trim().startsWith('=') ? att.Name.trim().remove('=') : att.Name; 
            }
            try{
            insert doc;
            att.ParentId = doc.Id;
            insert att; 

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.info,'Uploaded successfully...'));
            if(isSF1){
                return new PageReference('/'+techViewId);
            }else{
                return new PageReference('/apex/TechnicalVerificationDocUpload?flg=true&id='+techViewId);
            }
        }Catch(Exception e){
            isErr = true;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,e.getMessage()));
        }
        finally{
                att.Body = null; // -- clears the viewstate
                att = new Attachment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public pageReference cancelDocument(){
        return new PageReference('/apex/TechnicalVerificationDocUpload?flg=true&id='+techViewId);
    }

    public PageReference cancelDocumentSF1(){
        return new PageReference('/'+techViewId);
    }
}
```

**Test Class :-**

```
@istest
public class AttachmentStatusUsingJSRemotingCtrlTest {
    static TestMethod void AttachmentTest(){
    Id stuRecType =Schema.SObjectType.Technical_Verification__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Post- Sanction').getRecordTypeId();
     Id stuRecType2 =Schema.SObjectType.Technical_Verification__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Pre-Sanction').getRecordTypeId();
     Id stuRecType3 =Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
     Id stuRecType4 =Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ISFCL - Vendor').getRecordTypeId();
     Id VRrecType =Schema.SObjectType.Vendor_Request__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Technical').getRecordTypeId();

    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    User u = new User();
    u.Alias = 'standt';
    u.Email='accounts@indiashelter.in.uatgeo'; 
    u.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8'; 
    u.LastName='Testing'; 
    u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
    u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
    u.ProfileId = p.Id;      
    u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles'; 
    u.UserName='jatin999@gmail.com';
    insert u;

     RecordType myRecordType = [select id from RecordType where SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=True limit 1];

     Account acc1 = new Account();
     acc1.FirstName='test';
     acc1.LastName='Acc';
     acc1.Recordtypeid = stuRecType4;
     insert acc1;

     /*Contact con = new contact();
     //con.AccountId =acc1.id;
     con.Lastname = 'test';
     insert con; */

     Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
     opp.name='fdsf';
     opp.StageName='Closed Won';
     opp.CloseDate=system.today();
     opp.AccountId =acc1.id;
     insert opp;

    Vendor_Request__c van2= new Vendor_Request__c ();
    van2.RecordTypeId = VRrecType ;
    van2.Report_Type__c='24-Pre-Sanction Technical Report 1';
    //van2.Vendor_Name__c= acc1.id;
    van2.Request_Type__c = 'Technical';
    van2.Application__c=opp.id;
    van2.Loan_Purpose__c='Purchase';
    van2.Prior_Disbursement__c=454;
    van2.Vendor_Name_User__c = u.id;
    insert van2;

    Technical_Verification__c tech=new Technical_Verification__c();
     tech.Property_Type__c='Vacant Land';
     tech.Loan_Purpose__c='Purchase';
     tech.Visit_Done__c='12541';
     tech.Vendor_Request__c=van2.id;
     tech.Status__c='Generated';
     //acc.recordtypeId=stuRecType;
     //tech.AttachmentIds__c = '12';
     tech.Units_Land_Measurement__c='Meter';
     tech.Relationship_with_the_owner__c='Self';
     tech.Property_Situated_At__c='Panchayat';
     tech.Is_Construction_as_per_Sanction_Plan__c='Yes';
     tech.Local_Building_Bye_Laws_Followed__c='Yes';
     tech.Disbursal_Recommendation_Status__c='Positive';
     tech.Approval_No__c='25';
     tech.Approval_Date__c=system.today();
     insert tech; 

        document__c document1 = new  document__c();
        document1.Document_Name__c = 'My.Document';
        document1.Technical_Verification__c=tech.id;
        insert document1;


        attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        attach.body=bodyBlob;
        attach.parentId=document1.id;
        attach.ContentType ='image';
        insert attach; 



        PageReference pageRef = Page.AttachmentStatusUsingJSRemoting;
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', tech.id);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(tech);
        AttachmentStatusUsingJSRemotingCtrl attach1=New AttachmentStatusUsingJSRemotingCtrl(sc);
         attach1.saveProcess();
        //attach.init();
        attach1.saveDocument();
         attach1.saveDocumentSF1();
        attach1.loaderFlag=true;
        attach1.cancelDocument();
        attach1.cancelDocumentSF1();
        attach1.isErr=false;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method you are trying to call accepts boolean variable as a parameter

```
     @testvisible private  pageReference saveProcess(Boolean isSF1)
```

while you are invoking a method with no parameters

```
     attach1.saveProcess(); //incorrect
```

should be one of these:

```
     attach1.saveProcess(true);
     attach1.saveProcess(false);
```